# How to stop media recorder and go to another activity in android

Tags: android

How do I stop the media recorder and go to another activity in android? I have set setMaxduration in media recorder. How do I check if maxduration has been reached? I have to stop the media recorder and go to another activity.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the onInfo listener to listen for the event and then start the other activity.

Use the following code snippet:

```
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(); 
//... all your setup stuff ... 

mediaRecorder.setOnInfoListener(new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener(){ 
    @Override 
    public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) { 

        if(what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED ) { 
           startActivity(new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), ANOTHERACTIVITY.class)); 
        } 
    } 
});
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: whether i have to stop media recorder

Comment: According to the android developer site, Stopping happens asynchronously, there is no guarantee that the recorder will have stopped by the time the listener is notified. Also, there is no direct way to get the current state of the MediaRecorder. So you could probably call stop(), wrap it around an appropriate try-catch.. And then don't forget to call release().